# VizChart on dialog in SAP UI5

Tags: dialog, sapui5

I am trying to add a Viz chart on my Dialog Box in SAP UI5, but nothings gets displayed. Here is my code, can someone please help! I added a dialog box on a press which is working fine. Even i put alerts in various part just to check if the code is running proper. There is no error, still i dont see the chart in dialog box.

```
    pressTemp: function() {
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oDialog = oView.byId("helloSiteDialog");

        // create dialog lazily
        if (!oDialog) {

            // create dialog via fragment factory
            oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "Hari_At_Work.view.HelloSiteDialog", this);
            var oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");

            oVizFrame.destroyDataset();
            oVizFrame.destroyFeeds();

            console.log("chart here");

            //New dataset
            oVizFrame.setDataset(new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
                dimensions: [{
                    name: 'Timeline',
                    value: "{Country}"
                }],
                measures: [{
                    name: 'Value',
                    value: '{revenue}'
                }],
                data : {
    path : "/businessData"
} 
            }));

            alert("Dataset found");

            //Add feeds
            oVizFrame.addFeed(new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                uid: "categoryAxis",
                type: "Dimension",
                values: ["Timeline"]
            }));

            oVizFrame.addFeed(new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
                uid: "valueAxis",
                type: "Measure",
                values: ["Value"]
            }));

        //  oVizFrame.setModel(sap.ui.getCore().getModel());

            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
                businessData: [{
                    Country: "Canada",
                    revenue: 410.87,
                    profit: -141.25,
                    population: 34789000
                }, {
                    Country: "China",
                    revenue: 338.29,
                    profit: 133.82,
                    population: 1339724852
                }, {
                    Country: "France",
                    revenue: 487.66,
                    profit: 348.76,
                    population: 65350000
                }, {
                    Country: "Germany",
                    revenue: 470.23,
                    profit: 217.29,
                    population: 81799600
                }, {
                    Country: "India",
                    revenue: 170.93,
                    profit: 117.00,
                    population: 1210193422
                }, {
                    Country: "United States",
                    revenue: 905.08,
                    profit: 609.16,
                    population: 313490000
                }]
            });

            oVizFrame.setModel(oModel);
            alert("Model found");

            oView.addDependent(oDialog);

        }

        oDialog.open();
    //  oVizFrame.invalidate();

    },
```

My Fragment XML code:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"  xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds"
xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"  xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls" xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar">




<Dialog id="helloSiteDialog" title="Temperature Trend">


    <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
            height='100%' width="100%" vizType='column'>
            <viz:dataset>
                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/businessData}">
                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Name"
                            value="{Country}" />
                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                    <viz.data:measures>
                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue"
                            value="{revenue}" />
                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Cost"
                            value="{Cost}" />
                    </viz.data:measures>
                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
            </viz:dataset>

            <viz:feeds>
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                    values="Revenue" />
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension"
                    values="Name" />
            </viz:feeds>
        </viz:VizFrame>




    <beginButton>
        <Button text="Close" press="onCloseSiteDialog"/>
    </beginButton>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Also paste view and fragment code..I have tried your code.The map is showing for me see sample in plunkr.Are you getting any error in console?
[Plunk of vizframe](http://plnkr.co/edit/8fTdyJM0aBOcRWsK549Z?p=preview)

I have used popover.so change in code is only

```
oDialog.openBy(btn);
```

Comment: Fragment has just a normal VizChart code with `id="idVizFrame"`. My view has nothing to do with the control actually. All happening on a press action. Eg consider on click of a button supposedly.

Comment: Ya, the code it fine. As i said, its working if i use it in a different View(page). But in the Dialog Box its not appearing. The requirement is to display it in Dialog box!

Comment: In the plunker code, the graph shows just once. If i click the second time, there is not chart.

Comment: Thats because of duplicate id's.when second time clicks fragment try to add the same viz with id oViz

Comment: How to stop the same viz id situation? Also my chart is not displaying even after using a Popover. Its not working

Comment: have you added sap.viz in index.html?

Comment: I have resolved same id situation.[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8fTdyJM0aBOcRWsK549Z?p=preview)

Comment: My view is in xml, so ya sap.viz is added in my fragment where i have put the viz chart in my dialog box content

Comment: also what changes did you make to resolve the Same id issue?

Comment: Maybe it helps for debugging if you create a plunkr sample using all your relevant coding.
In plunkr you can also add new files, so no need to put it all in the index.html.

Comment: Thanks, it worked @techippo.com. I created the popover in js itself. If i create it in XML, it was not rendering for some reason.

Comment: Also, can you also please tell where in the code have we stated which type of chart (column, bar, line etc) is added and also size etc.

Comment: We did not add viz type any where in code.Default value is column.If you need to change type you can either add it in constructor of fragment by 'vizType' or you can use setVizType method.`var vizFrame = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame({
 'vizType' : 'bar'
});`.Never set type at runtime.You should go with first method

Answer (score 0):

One Solution for a map inside a dialog box can be
`<d:Dialog> <html:div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 500px;'> Add you map content here </html:div> </d:Dialog>`